# How do I boot Linux if the boot partition was deleted?

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot

At first, Windows 7 was the only OS in the drive.

Then I installed Linux Mint. I accidentally formatted the `sda1` partition (where the Windows 7 bootloader was stored) as ext4, being the mount point of `/boot`. As a result, I couldn't boot Win7 any more.

(By the way, Mint was installed in the sda5 partition)

Afterwards, I repaired the Win7 bootloader successfully, which deleted the GRUB(2?) loader, resulting in me being unable to boot Mint.

I tried running:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

Resulting message is:

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot (is /dev mounted?).
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

And after reboot, I get the `grub>` prompt, but no OS options whatsoever.

(Keep in mind, there's no partition assigned for `/boot`)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `grub-install`, enter the grub interactive shell and use these commands to install the bootloader correctly. Use your correct partition numbers.

```
root (hd0,0) (where is /boot with /boot/grub/grub.conf and grub stages files ?)
setup (hd0) (where do you want to install the bootloader?)
exit
```

`grub-install` probably needs a `/etc/mtab`. If you wish to use `grub-install`, firstly copy `/etc/mtab` into `/mnt/etc/mtab` (don't worry about overwriting the older file, it's updated on every boot) then chroot into `/mnt`, and run your MINT `grub-install` script, inside the chroot.

Comment: A note on partition numbers: `hd0 = sda`, `hd1 = sdb`, etc.; `(hd0,0) = sda1`, `(hd0,1) = sda2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have grub (if using Mint, `apt-get install grub`). Then run what Spidey posted. If you get error 15, quit the shell and run update-grub. It should ask you if you want to make a menu.lst, confirm yes. After that, try what Spidey posted and it should work.